# Display toast for empty fields when user submits data

Tags: android, android-edittext, toast

I have an activity in which there are three EditTexts: First Name, Middle Name, Last Name, and a Submit button. If the user submits with a field blank, a different `toast` appears for different field. Here's is an example when button will be clicked!:

[image]

Comment: Please let me know how my answer works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you can figure out how to use a button listener yourself. Inside that button listener, you can use this code:

```
// create EditText references
EditText etFirstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstName);
EditText etMiddleName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.middleName);
EditText etLastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastName);

// boolean variables that each represent whether or not the each field is blank
// if the EditText length is 0, it's true (blank); otherwise, it's false (filled)
boolean firstNameBlank = etFirstName.length() == 0;
boolean middleNameBlank = etMiddleName.length() == 0;
boolean lastNameBlank = etLastName.length() == 0;

if (firstNameBlank && middleNameBlank && lastNameBlank) {
    // toast all three blank  
}
else if (firstNameBlank && middleNameBlank) {
    // toast just first and middle are blank
}
else if (firstNameBlank && lastNameBlank) {
    // toast just first and last are blank
}
else if (middleNameBlank && lastNameBlank) {
    // toast just middle and last are blank
}
else if (firstNameBlank) {
    // toast just first is blank
}
else if (middleNameBlank) {
    // toast just middle is blank
}
else if (lastNameBlank) {
    // toast just last is blank
}
else {
    // none are blank
}
```

Comment: Thnx  a million!!!!!!!!!!! you are just awesome. Your answer did the trick, that's exactly what i was looking for. I didn't mention first & middle, first & last, middle & last fields. But your code did it all, i'm right now dancing, hehe....  thnx once again,

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
EditText e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EDITTEXT));
if(e.getText().length == 0){
//Show Toast
}else{
//continue your code
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at that image first, i tried multiple methods, the toasts are appearing at the same time one after each.

Comment: so??..get the id of particular edit box for which u need validation and do same as i suggested

Answer (score 0):

implement `onClick()` event of your submit `button` as below:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    super.onClick(view);


    switch (view.getId()) {
         case R.id.btnSubmit:
                if(edtFirstName.getText().toString().length() < 1){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "please fill all boxes.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(edtSecondName.getText().toString().length() < 1){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "please fill middle name and last name.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if(edtLastName.getText().toString().length() < 1){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "please fill last name.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "please wait...processing.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
             break; 

         default:
               break;

        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried your code, but what i needed was mike yaworski's one, thnx for your help thou. You can take a look at his answer, that's what i was actually ooking for. Please don't get me wrong. Thnx for your precious time.